# Why does java have Type when it already has Object?

Tags: java, object, types

I was hoping that someone could tell me why java has [`java.lang.reflect.Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html), when everything already inherits from `Object`?

Could someone please give an example of a case where I would need to use a `Type` and not an `Object`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Object` is a base class for all java classes. `Type` is just an tag interface for all classes that represent types. It was introduced in java 1.5 because prior to java 1.5 there was no classes that represent java type except `java.lang.Class`. Then when generics were introduced there was a need to create some general abstraction common for `Class`, generic array etc. So they defined interface `Type`.

Comment: Indeed. The key thing that OP may have missed is that every `Class` is itself an `Object`.

Comment: So, I would use Type when I need to have many different Object.class?

Comment: No, you would use `Type` when you use an API that returns one. No other occasion to do so, and indeed no other way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

'Object' is the supertype for all classes, 'Class' is a class defining a class and 'Type' is a supertype that also covers primitive types (int, boolean, etc).

Comment: Completely incorrect. See the Javadoc. `Object` is not a supertype. `Type` isn't a supertype either, it's an `interface`; it doesn't cover primitive types; and is used only for Generics. -1

Comment: Here is what javadoc says about java.lang.reflect.Type: "Type is the common superinterface **for all types** in the Java programming language. These include raw types, parameterized types, array types, type variables and **primitive types**".